# Results from query are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I have been adding custom functionality in Strapi code through the controller.
The below result variable comes up as undefined. If I return the result variable directly in the function the result is correctly returned in the http response. Is there any issues in the syntax below ? I appreciate any help i can get.

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Read the documentation (https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/controllers.html#core-controllers)
 * to customize this controller
 */
module.exports = {

    async getItemAggregate (context) {
        var itemid = context.params.itemid
        strapi.log.info(itemid)
        strapi.log.info("test aggregate");
        const result = await strapi.query('aggregate').findOne({"id": itemid});
        strapi.log.info(result)
        // const fields = result.toObject();
        // strapi.log.info(result)

        // entities = await strapi.services.aggregate.search({"id":1});
        // entities2 = await strapi.services.item.search({"id":1});
        // strapi.log.info(entities)
        strapi.log.info(result)

        // strapi.log.info(entities2)
        //get latest aggregate

        //get latest tranacitons
    }
};
```

Comment: Could you solve it?

Comment: Hi
Sorry for the late reply. i couldn't but we had other issues with the project so i never fix it. I was thinking of using play on request call to get around the problem. Since it works with the result returned directly.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. The thing I found out is that `strapi.log.<function>` doesn't stringify the query. Try logging the query wrapped with `JSON.stringify(<query>)`.
Like this:

```js
const result = await strapi.query('aggregate').findOne({"id": itemid});
strapi.log.info(JSON.stringify(result));
```